Sending float continuously from python to arduino via serial
I'm trying to send lots of float data from python to arduino. But when I check the values, some of them are wrong.
the part of python code:
arduino = serial.Serial(port=args.port, baudrate=115200, timeout=5000)

print(feature[0:50])
# Send each float in a feature
for num in feature:
    arduino.write(bytes(str("%f" % num), "ascii") + bytes("\n", "ascii"))

# Receive the input back
recv_features = []
for _ in range(len(feature)):
    recv = arduino.read_until()
    recv_features.append(float(recv.decode(encoding="ascii")))
print(recv_features[0:50])

where feature is a list with 1440 floats.
the arduino code:
#define INPUT_LEN 10
char X_test_byteArr[INPUT_LEN];
float data[1440];
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.setTimeout(5000);
}

void loop() {
    size_t num_read;
    // Receive every input as string, convert to float
    while (Serial.available()==0) {}
    for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i++) {
        // Wait for input data
        while (Serial.available()==0) {}
        // Read input string
        num_read = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', X_test_byteArr, INPUT_LEN);
        X_test_byteArr[num_read] = '\0';
        // Convert input string to float
        data[i] = float(atof(X_test_byteArr));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1440; ++i) {
        Serial.println(data[i]);
    }
}

Here is the sent data:
[-1.12,  0.32, -0.48, -0.84,  3.01,
  0.03, -0.80,  0.23, -0.69,  1.02,
  0.55,  0.24, -0.13, -0.55, -1.42,
  4.20,  0.05,  0.04,  0.29, -0.45,
 -0.12,  0.21, -0.81, -0.07,  1.03,
 -0.09, -0.01,  0.38, -0.99,  1.59,
  0.21, -0.18,  0.03,  0.39,  1.38,
  0.76, -0.15, -0.25,  0.23, -0.02,
  0.00, -0.48, -0.27,  0.19, -0.09,
 -1.77,  0.24, -0.52, -0.08,  0.43]

and the received data in python:
[-1.12,  0.32, -0.48, -0.84,  3.01,
  0.03, -0.80,  0.23, -0.69,  1.02,
  0.55,  0.24, -0.13, -0.55, -1.42,
  4.20,  0.05,  0.04,  0.29, -0.45,
 -0.12,  0.21, -0.81, -0.07,  1.03,
 -0.09, -0.01, 37987,  0.00, -0.99,
 59294,  0.21, -0.18,  0.03,  0.39,
  1.38,  0.76,  0.00, -0.15, -0.25,
 22918,  0.00, -0.02,  0.00, -0.48,
 -0.27, 19308, -0.09, -1.77,  0.24]

I guess add some delay can fix it, but any better method can speed up the whole progress? Thanks for any idea.

Seems like you're using the round-trip results for comparison. What debugging have you done to determine which transfer (or both) is causing "wrong" data? IOW you need to try to reduce the scope of the problem.

What kind of Arduino board you are using? If you are using an Arduino Uno, it only has 2kB of RAM. Each float is 4-bytes, so 1440*4=5760 bytes, which is bigger than the total RAM available in Arduino Uno.

what's the point of this?  https://xyproblem.info ?

@sawdust I added Serial.println(); after readBytesUntil in the first for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i++) loop on the arduino side, and added arduino.read_until() in the for num in feature: loop on the python side. This works, but wastes double time. So I think the problem is python sent data too fast and error occurred during the transfer.

@hcheung I'm using Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense, which has 256k ram. I think that's enough.

To validate a transfer I'd rather see a checksum (or even better: CRC32) of the data. Treat the array of 1440 floats as an array of 2880 integers, and calculate the checksum prior to transmission. The Arduino would then do similar after reception is complete. This check would also alleviate @hcheung 's concern regarding storage.
